# Why does link_to method post, target blank not open in a new tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following does not open a new tab. Instead it opens on the current tab:

```
link_to ... :method => :post, :target => '_blank'
```

HTML returns:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/foobar/videos/abc/buy">Foobar</a>
```

I hear you can't post to a new window with Rails helpers. Until I read this:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2885 (posted 4 months ago though).

A workaround would also be appreciated. However, more importantly I am looking for a reason why it is behaving the way it is.

Comment: Do you have some JavaScript that picks up `data-method="post"` and changes how the link works?

Comment: Nope, you can try this on your env. I thought this was a 3.2.2 issue until I tried with Rails 3.2.8. Same issue.

Comment: It appears to be fixed in https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/888be8adcb7d609f442b3883dc722. Try to `bundle update jquery-rails` itself to the latest version (which is `2.1.1`).

Comment: @ronalchn perfect! Post this as an answer, and I will select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be fixed in https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/888be8adcb7d609f442b3883dc722.

"jquery-ujs" is distributed as part of the "jquery-rails" gem.

Try to `bundle update jquery-rails` itself to the latest version (which is 2.1.1).